# Showing $f'(0)=0$ where $f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ for $x \neq 0$, and $f(0) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

In the following problem I need to consider the function defined by $f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ if $x\ne 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$

I am trying to show that $f'(0)=0$.

By calculating the derivative of f(x) I got the following,

$$\frac{2e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}}{x^3}$$ when $x\ne 0$ and clearly the derivative of the second part , $0$ remains $0$

so since I am trying to show that $f'(0)=0$ since $x=0$ I thought I could only use the second part where $0$ if $x=0$. So therefore  $f'(0)=0$

Just looking to get some reassurance that this is the correct method to solve this problem

Comment: You must go to the definition of derivative.

Comment: By this logic, any function is differentiable at any point.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must go to the definition:

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}x=0$$

Comment: how did you use the definition to get that fraction?

Comment: @Jh $$g'(0):=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x$$

Comment: By the definition

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x},$$

and more generally

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: so then is $g(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ an $g(0)=0$?

Comment: For $x>0$, yes. That's how you defined $f$, right?

Comment: yes it is, thanks for your help